# X509Certificate2 usage issues since moving to Azure App Service

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, x509certificate2

I have several remote servers that communicate with a central SOAP Service, where they can download the latest X509Certificate2 which can then be used to call a third-party API that requires this certificate to authenticate the requests.

Some of these remote servers are hosted by some of our clients on their own Windows Servers, which may be VMs or physical boxes, and others are hosted by us on Azure VMs.

We have had no previous issue with this functionality until recently when we moved our APIs from being hosted on a physical box to now being hosted in an Azure App Service (with an App Gateway handling requests).

What now happens is that all of the non-Azure servers, download the certificate successfully, but the certificate fails when used with the third-party rejecting the certificate with the error:

> *The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.*

I have confirmed that if I manually copy the certificate to the servers, it works fine, but for some reason somewhere in the process of downloading it from the Azure SOAP API it now fails.

The code that we have to export the certificate on the API side so that it can be downloaded is something like:

```
[WebMethod]
public ClientCertificateMessage GetCertificate(LoginMessage login, string customer)
{
    ClientCertificateMessage returnValue = new ClientCertificateMessage(); 
    
    if (Authentication.VerifyLogin(login))
    {
        try
        {
            string filePathNameCertificate = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathToLocalCert"].ToString() + customer + ".p12";
            string filePathNamePassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathToLocalCert"].ToString() + customer + ".txt";
            
            string password = File.ReadAllText(filePathNamePassword);

            X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2( filePathNameCertificate, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            returnValue.Certificate = x509Certificate2.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, password);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log Error stuff here is removed
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // error stuff here is removed
    }
    return returnValue; 
}
```

The service that retrieves this certificate and uses it looks like:

```
public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(int certificateID, string password, string customer)
{
    X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2 = null;
    
    try
    {
        SoapClient client = new SoapClient();
        
        Login login = CreateLogin();
        
        ClientCertificateMessage clientCertificateMessage = null;
        
        try
        {
            clientCertificateMessage = client.GetCertificate(login, customer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // error logging removed
        }
        
        if ((clientCertificateMessage != null) && (clientCertificateMessage.Certificate != null))
        {
            using (CertificateData cd = new CertificateData())
            {
                dynamic revisedCertificate = new ExpandoObject();
                revisedCertificate.Certificate = clientCertificateMessage.Certificate;
                
                cd.Update(revisedCertificate, certificateID); // Save certificate data in database for later use
            }

            x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(clientCertificateMessage.Certificate, password);
        }
        else
        {
            // handle logic got no certificate remove
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // error logging removed
    }
    return x509Certificate2;
}
```

I cannot see anything that would explain why VMs on Azure continue to work, but all other VMs do not.  We know those other servers can communicate and download the certificate, and when recreating the certificate from the byte array saved in the database the thumbprint and everything else matches.

I have seen other articles regarding Certificates on App Services where you need add Settings for WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES or WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE, however, we have not done this as the certificates do not fail to be generated.

Is there anything that I am missing where perhaps some odd Azure configuration or even some obvious technical reason for why a certificate downloaded fails, but the same certificate manually copied to the server works?

Thanks in advance for helping out.

Comment: are you specifying a real path on ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathToLocalCert"].ToString()  variable? I mean... d:\wwwroot\ ... ?

Comment: Yes, the file exists, and the certificate is loaded successfully and returned by the API.

Comment: just as an experiment, have you tried calling directly Azure App Service endpoints bypassing App Gateway to see if it works?

Comment: An interesting one, no I haven't, I will give it a go.  Although still does not explain why calling it from an Azure VM has no problems.

Comment: Having tried skipping the App Gateway completely and going directly to the App Service, this issue is still occurring.

Comment: and if you manually copy the certificate to Azure App Service it works, correct?

Comment: Correct.  We have around 16 customers having the issue on their own hosted servers, and 6 customers on Azure hosted VMs with having no issue.

Comment: the only thing that comes to my mind is that string filePathNameCertificate = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathToLocalCert"].ToString() + customer + ".p12"; When using App Service it needs to be a relative path rather than a physical path.